# Defining two workspaces in ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, workspace

I need to first define the workspace where I can call my inputs from. I then need to define  a geodatabase so all the outputs run from the tools are stored in that geodatabase.

Any ideas?

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = "D:/GIS/Lab3"
fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

a = "streams.shp"
b = "basins.shp"
c = "forest.shp"

gdb_folder = "D:/GIS/Lab3"
gdb_name = "Q4.gdb"
arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(gdb_folder, gdb_name)

arcpy.env.workspace = "D:/GIS/Lab3/Geodatabase/Q4.gdb"
clip = arcpy.Clip_analysis(a, b, "streams_clip")
```

Answer (score 3):

When ArcPy encounters a feature class, shapefile or table without a pathname it assumes that it needs to be read from or written to the current workspace which is set using `arcpy.env.workspace`.

When you need to read from one workspace and write to another within a tool's parameters you will need to use a pathname to one or other of your workspaces and provide a full qualified path instead.

You could try using this untested code to get you past where you are stuck:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = "D:/GIS/Lab3"

a = "streams.shp"
b = "basins.shp"
c = "forest.shp"

gdb_folder = "D:/GIS/Lab3"
gdb_name = "Q4.gdb"
arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(gdb_folder, gdb_name)
outputWorkspace = "{0}/{1}".format(gdb_folder, gdb_name)

arcpy.Clip_analysis(a, b, "{0}/{1}".format(outputWorkspace, "streams_clip"))
```

To assemble my pathnames I prefer using Python string formatting over other methods.